# css z-index issues, placing a div infront of a container div

Tags: css

i have several divs on a page, one of which is a container, and the other content, both of which i dont want to alter. i have another div #more which i want to be ontop of or infront of the container. Can you help at all?

```
     @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#000;
    font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC";
    margin:5%;  
    margin-top:2%;
}

#logo {
    z-index:1;
}

#code {
    margin-top:10%;
    padding-top:2em;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:2;
}

a:link {color:#FFF;
        text-decoration:none;
}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#FFF;
            text-decoration:none;
}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FFF;            
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
}  /* mouse over link */



a:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 200px #ccc;
}

a:active {color:#FFF;
            text-decoration:none;
} /*active link */

p { padding: 0px; }

#contact_form_holder { 
    margin-left:33%;
    margin-top:5%;
    font-variant: small-caps; /* making the small letter looks like capital but keeping the size of it to smaller, looks cool */  
    width:400px; /* setting a fixed width of the contact form holder will make things easier later (like aligning and such) */  
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:#CCC 0px 0px 50px 10px; 
    padding:15px;
}


#contact_form_holder input, #contact_form_holder textarea {  
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:#FFF solid;
    box-shadow:#CCC 0px 0px 10px; 
    width:80%; /* make all the inputs and the textarea same size (100% of the div they are into) */  
    font-family:  Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif ; /* we must set this, so it inherits the font-family */  
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:5px; /* and make a custom padding, you can set whatever you like */  

}  
#contact_form_holder textarea {  
    height:100px; /* i never liked small textareas, so make it 100px in height */
}  
#send_message {  
    width:200px !important; /* the width of the submit button  */  
    font-variant: small-caps;/* nicer font-variant (like explained before) */ 
    border:1px solid black; /* remove the default border and put a normal black one */  
    cursor:pointer;  
    cursor:hand;    
}  

#cf_submit_p { text-align:rightright; } /* show the submit button aligned with the right side */  

.error {  
    display: none; /* hide the errors */  
                   /* add some styling */  
    padding:5px;  
    color: #D8000C;  
    font-size:14px;  
    background-color: #FFBABA;  
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;

}  
.success {  
    display: none; /* hide the sucess div */  
    /* add some styling */  
    padding:5px;  
    color: #044406;  
    font-size:12px;  
    background-color: #B7FBB9;  
}  

#contact_logo { 
    padding-left:170px;
}

.error img { vertical-align:top; }  

#instructions {
    background:#F00;
}

#more {
    z-index:100;
}


.fb-like {
    float:left;
}

h1.main,p.demos {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.sp-container h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
        -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
        -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
        -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
    font-size: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
        -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
        -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
        -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
        animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
    animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
    animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 282px;
    height: 273px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
    background: transparent  url(images/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
        -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
        -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
        -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
        -o-transform: scale(5);
        -ms-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
        -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
        -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
    animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #FC0;
    text-shadow:none;
}

#find {
    padding-top:25%;
}

/**/
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%,75%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.4;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%,75%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.4;
        -moz-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/
@keyframes blurFadeInOut{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%,75%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0.4;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.2;
        transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of CSS.  I think your best bet to get help is going to be to simplify the CSS down to what you are trying to do, and also show us the (SIMPLE) html.  Put it in a jsfiddle perhaps?  There's too much cruft here that's entirely irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: you added a z-index, but that'll only work if you also add relative or absolute positioning...

Answer (score 3):

z-index only works when the div element has a position of `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`

Example:

```
#logo {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#code {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10%;
    padding-top:2em;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your classes and IDs that have a z-index a position property (either position:fixed, position:relative or position:absolute) and your z-index will work.

If your div isn't positioned absolutely or fixed and is a normal div placement, use position:relative.